# How to prove some properties of partitions of finite subsets of N?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ramsey-theory, set-partition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any partition of {1,2,..,9} must contain a 3-Term Arithmetic Progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239839/any-partition-of-1-2-9-must-contain-a-3-term-arithmetic-progression)

The problem is as such:

> Prove that there is not a partition of $N_9 = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ consisting of two sets (the set $N_9$ could not be partitioned into two sets), such that both sets do not contain three elements of an arithmetic progression ($a_n = a_0 + (n-1)d$). Such a partition exists for $N_8 = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.

A basic example of a partition of $N_9$ is $P = \{\{1,3,4\}, \{2,5,6,7,8,9\}\}$. It is evident that in this case, there are three elements in the second set that belong to the same arithmetic progression. Leaving examples aside, I have no idea on how a proof for this property would look like. Could anyone assist in generating a proof for this property?

Comment: You found a counterexample

Comment: @Amr: no, that's just an example

Comment: @Amr That is not a counterexample. In the second set, 2, 5, 8 are elements of an arithmetic progression, and also 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 are elements of another arithmetic progression.

Comment: @Amr: The second set contains the progression $\{5,7,9\}$.

Comment: @Ilya Yes Now I see

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: as well as $\{5,6,7\}$ :)

Comment: Alex, notice that if $d = 3$ then the 3rd member shall be at least $10$, so you shall only take care of $d = 1,2$. The example for $N_8$  is $\{1,3,4,6\}\cup\{2,5,7,8\}$

Comment: @Ilya I don't see what is your point, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Alex: nevermind, that part of the comment is incorrect

Comment: Feeling stupid here, but definition should be $a_n = a_{n-1} + d$, not the above, right?

Comment: @gnometorule Yes, I made a mistake. I corrected it to provide a non-recursive definition for the progression.