# Can you partition the set of 9 consecutive integers 1 to 9 in 2 sets, s.t. no member of either set is the mean of two other members of the same set?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, average, pigeonhole-principle, means, set-partition

Is it possible to partition the set $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ in two subsets $\Omega=A\cup B$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$, such that no member of either subset is the mean of two other members of the same subset, i.e. such that the following condition holds?
$$
\forall X\in\{A,B\}\forall x\in X\forall y,z\in X\setminus\{x\}\bullet y\neq z\implies x\neq\frac{y+z}{2}
$$

The answer is: no, such a partition is impossible. This can be proven, e.g. by creating a tree of all possible partitions, and excluding each leaf.

I managed to write a proof that is more elegant than the brute-force method just described, but even so, it isn't particularly enlightening. I wonder if there is some insightful way of proving this result succinctly, possibly making a clever use of the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: First, there are only 9 integers in your set.  Second, there are lots of partitions that satisfy the criterion.  $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ or $A=\{1\}$ or $A=\emptyset.$

Comment: @B.Goddard You are right about the number of integers. Thanks for pointing out. I've corrected the title. But you are wrong about the partitions. For instance, in the first and third of your partitions $2=\frac{1+3}{2}$. In your second partition $3=\frac{2+4}{2}$.

Comment: Then what's the point of the partition?  You can take two numbers from $A$ or two numbers from $B$ and they're in the same set.  One set has to have two even numbers and their average has to be in one of $A$ or $B$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239839/ also has some very brief proofs.

Comment: @MJD Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, can the set $[9]=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ be partitioned into two sets, neither of which contains a $3$-term arithmetic progression? The answer is **no** because the [Van der Waerden number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden_number) $W(2,3)$ is equal to $9$. It took me a few minutes to verify this by hand with the obvious backtrack algorithm.

Of course $9$ is best possible here since
$$[8]=\{1,2,5,6\}\cup\{3,4,7,8\}=\{1,3,6,8\}\cup\{2,4,5,7\}=\{1,4,5,8\}\cup\{2,3,6,7\}.$$

Here is my work showing that $W(2,3)=9$. The notation $0010011$ means that the numbers $1$, $2$, $4$, and $5$ go into one set, while the numbers $3$, $6$, and $7$ go into the other set, and putting $8$ into either set will create a $3$-term A.P.

$0010011$
$001011$
$00110011$
$0011010$
$0011011$
$0100101$
$010011$
$0101100$
$01011010$
$01100110$
$011010$
$011011$

Answer (score 1):

Notice your question is really can I partition $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ into two sets $A$ and $B$ such that there are no three-term arithmetic progressions in either set. From here after a bit of messing around one might suspect that every $5$ term subset must contain an arithmetic progression of three terms, but this turns out to be false as the set $\{1,3,4,8,9\}$ exists. With this our hopes of a pigeonhole-based solution kind of go out the window, and for this reason, the proof for this modified version of the question is generally something of the following form.

$1$. Pick an arithmetic triple, say $(1,5,9)$, and notice we are forced to partition them into one of the following $\{(1,5),(9)\}$ or $\{(1,9),(5)\}$. (Using the mapping $x\mapsto{10-x}$ we see that $\{(1,5),(9)\}$ is equivalent to $\{(5,9),(1)\}$.)

$2$. Now place $1$ and $5$ in $A$ and $9$ in $B$, then $3$ also can't be in $A$ so place it in $B$, but then $6$ must go in $A$, and going through the mental gymnastics we end up with $A=\{1,5,6,8\}$ and $B=\{3,4,7,9\}$ and we see that $2$ can't go in either set so we are done with this case.

$3$. Consider $1$ and $9$ in $A$ and $5$ in $B$, then we are left to do two sub-cases, one where some other term, say $2$ is in $A$ and another case with $2$ in $B$. Either way, we see that it's impossible to not have a three-term arithmetic progression once more and so the proof is complete.

For a potential glimmer of hope regarding some pigeonhole-based proof notice for any given term in $S$, there are at least $4$ arithmetic progressions containing that term. For instance $9$ has $(7,8,9)$, $(5,7,9)$, $(3,6,9)$, and $(1,5,9)$. You might be able to find a way to work with that, but I haven't seen anything thus far.