# Graham's number of layer 1 tetration explanation?

Tags: tetration

I have a question on how the number of the first layer of the Graham's number ($g_1$) is computed.

From Wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number#Magnitude

$g_1 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 $

[image]

As I understand it, this means that the number of the first layer of the Graham's number $g_1$ is a tetration ($\uparrow\uparrow$) in the form:

$$g_1 = 3^{3^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{3}}}}}} = \,{}^{n}3$$

Where $n$ is:

$3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow3) = \,{}^{7625597484987}3$

Thus, the height of the tower, is this what Wikipedia says?

If so, now, if:

$$3\uparrow\uparrow3 = \,{}^{3}3 = 3^{3^{3}}$$

$$3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow3)= \,{}^{3\uparrow\uparrow3}3 = \,{}^{7625597484987}3$$

Why `g1` is (as in the posted link):

$$g_1 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3)$$

And not:

$$g_1 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3)$$

??? Anyway, why:

$\,\,3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3)\,\,\,\,\,$
is $\,\,\,\,\,3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow ... (3\uparrow\uparrow3)...))$

Comment: A discussion of this can also be found at http://www.mpmueller.net/reihenalgebra.pdf (However I don't know whether this is really helpful for you, since your notations seem to be very similar to that what I remember from an early version of the article)

Comment: Thanks for the link! After rereading the example on Wikipedia I understood the principle: $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$ refers to a recursive-recursive tetration repeated 3 times ($3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3) = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow3))$ which in turn means a recursive tetration repeated $3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow3)$ times, where  $3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow3)$ is not the height of the tower, but the *number of tetrations* which overwrap one after each other, leading to an even bigger number.

Comment: Possibly of interest: [Graham's Number : Why so big?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163423/grahams-number-why-so-big)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=3\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow3)$ is wrong there.

Hyperoperation (from tetration and so on) written in Knuth's notation satisfy the relation: $a\uparrow^nb=a\uparrow^{n-1}a\uparrow^{n-1}a\uparrow^{n-1}\dots \uparrow^{n-1}a$ where $n$ is the number of arrows, and $\uparrow^{n-1}$ is iterated b times.

So the first layer which is $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow2$ or (more usually) $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$ is equal to:

$3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow3)=3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow7625597484987)$

So after you exponentiate 3 to itself 7625597484987 times you get how many times you have to tetrate 3 to itself, and that's only the first layer!

Comment: Yeah, that's a really big thing, can't even imagine it with a number...

Comment: We can't imagine it, it has more digit than particles in the whole universe! If you try to compute that with your mind you'll probably collapse in a blackhole. (I don't remember where i read this).

Comment: And trying to compute the Ackermann's function of two Graham's number (xkcd -> http://xkcd.com/207/) as parameters will probably make the whole universe collapse in a blackhole. Not saying about what's behind of it, if anything.

Comment: Your 1st sentence states an inequality, which is **true** :).