# How do I write Grahams number

Tags: tetration, big-numbers

I found that  Graham's number is :

[image]

So, can we say that it is equal to $3^x$ with $x$ is a power tower of 63 3's?

Comment: Not even close.

Comment: To understand how Graham's number is defined it is necessary to know Knut's up-arrow-notation.

Comment: The size difference between Graham's number and what you suggest is almost exactly Graham's number.

Comment: In Conway's array notation (look here  : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway_chained_arrow_notation   for the rules) it is known that $3\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 64\rightarrow 2<$Graham'snumber <$\ 3\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 65\rightarrow 2$

Comment: Of possible interest is my 4 March 2002 sci.math post [GRAHAM'S NUMBER AND RAPIDLY GROWING FUNCTIONS](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=371174).

Comment: Possibly useful: [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163423/grahams-number-why-so-big](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163423/grahams-number-why-so-big/1046098) “We introduce a calibration function $F(m,n)$ with which me may compare our estimate of [Graham's number]… It is recommended that the reader calculate a few small values of $F$ to get a feeling for its rate of growth, e.g. $F(5,5)$ or $F(10,3)$.”

Comment: @tinlyx you've been editing dozens of old question, bumping newer questions off the front page. Please stop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Knuth's up-arrow notation works as follows :

$a\uparrow b=a^b$

$a\uparrow \uparrow b=a\uparrow a\uparrow ...\uparrow a \uparrow a$ with $b$ $a's$

$a\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow b=a\uparrow \uparrow  a \uparrow \uparrow ... \uparrow \uparrow a \uparrow \uparrow a$ with $b$ $a's$

and so on.

Note that the calculation is done from **right** , so $3\uparrow \uparrow 3=3\uparrow (3\uparrow 3)$, **not** $(3\uparrow 3)\uparrow 3$.

Now, Graham's number is defined as follows.

Notice the sequence

$G_0=4$ , $G_{n+1}=3\uparrow^{G(n)}3 $ for all $n\ge 0$

Then Graham's number is $G_{64}$.

Already $G_1=3\uparrow^4 3=3\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow\uparrow 3$ is so large that its magnitude cannot be comprehended. $G_2$ already has $G_1$ up-arrows,
$G_3$ has $G_2$ up-arrows and so on.

Just to imagine how big $G_1$ already is : First imagine the number
$$N:=3 \uparrow \uparrow 3 \uparrow \uparrow 3=3\uparrow \uparrow 3^{27}$$

This is a power tower of $3's$ with height $3^{27}$.

Now how to get $G_1$ :

Step $1$ : $3$

Step $2$ : $M_2 :$ a power tower with $3$ $3's$

Step $3$ : $M_3 :$ a power tower with $M_2$ $3's$

Step $4$ : $M_4 :$ a power tower with $M_3$ $3's$

and so on.

At step $N$, you reach $G_1$. It is already hard to describe how this number can be constructed. It is absolutely hopeless trying to comprend its size. Now you should get a feeling how insane big Graham's number is.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article [here](http://www.bum.io/grahams-number-an-enormous-number/) describing the progression. Here is the progression the way I understand it:

$$ 3\uparrow3 = 3^3 = 27 $$

$$ 3\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow3\uparrow3 = 3^{3^3} = 7,625,597,484,987  $$

$$ 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow(7,625,597,484,987) $$

Just to give you an idea of how big this is:

$$ 
\left.\begin{aligned}
3^{3^{3^{3^{⋰^{3}}}}} 
\end{aligned}\right\} 
\text{ height = 7,625,597,484,987}
$$

Now we can define G1:

$$ 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow(7,625,597,484,987)) $$

Now we can use the result in G1 to define G2:

$$ G2 = \underbrace{3\uparrow\uparrow ... \uparrow\uparrow 3}_{G1 \text{ up arrows}} $$

$$ G3 = \underbrace{3\uparrow\uparrow ... \uparrow\uparrow 3}_{G2 \text{ up arrows}} $$

$$ G4 = \underbrace{3\uparrow\uparrow ... \uparrow\uparrow 3}_{G3 \text{ up arrows}} $$

$$ ...$$

This keeps going until you get to:

$$ G64 = \underbrace{3\uparrow\uparrow ... \uparrow\uparrow 3}_{G63 \text{ up arrows}} $$

And that's Graham's number. It's a HUGE number.

Comment: Hmm, just to recover form the ***<GASP>*** (tm) Don Martin RIP : any alternating geometric series with quotient $q \gt 1$ contains such numbers and even larger numbers  - for instance where the number of uparrows equals the Graham's number itself - but anyway converge to some very small, handy value; say if $q=2$ this monsters of numbers put themselves in a handy box of size $1/3$ ... which you can give to any high school pupil to play with  ;-)

Comment: Goodstein's sequence is a great example of a function that goes VERY big before eventually going back down to zero. It can generate numbers that put Graham's number to shame. Would love to know which sequences you were referring to.